# How can i draw a nice spiral in python with turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a homework to draw a spiral(from inside to outside) in python with turtle, but I cant think of a way to do that, beside what I did  its need to be like this:

[image]

I tried to do it like that, but its not working properly.

```
import turtle

turtle.shape ('turtle')


d = 20  #Distance

a = 1   #StartingAngle
x = 200    #Num of loops 

for i in range (x):
turtle.left(a)
turtle.forward(d)
a = a + 5
```

Comment: What is your error? Can you please edit your question and describe it?

Comment: Um, the link is blank for me. Case in point on why you should not give links to content, the question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are increasing the wrong variable in your loop.

A spiral is like a "circunference whose radius increases over time".

You should increase the `d` variable over time, and not the angle `a`. The amount of the increase of each loop will be essential to determine the appearance of your spiral, but you can obtain a good value for the increase with some calculation or by trial and error.

Comment: Tnx its help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
from math import sin,cos,pi

t=turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)

n=50 #number of spirals
d=10 #distance between 2 spirals
r=0  #radius
x,y = 0, 0

cur_r = r
for i in range(n):
    for a in range(1,360, 4):
        r = cur_r + d*a/360.0
        a *= pi/180.0
        y = r*sin(a)
        x = r*cos(a)
        turtle.goto(x,y)
    cur_r += d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

i=0
while i<4:
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.pensize(1+i)
    turtle.forward(1+i)
    t.color("blue")
    turtle.bgcolor("pink")
    t.lt(3)
    i+=0.003
```

If you are using program other than IDLE(such as pycharm), add

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

at the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

```py
import turtle as t

for i in range(360):
 t.circle(i,20)
```

[image]

Source: [Explained here](https://dev.to/taarimalta/how-to-draw-a-spiral-with-python-turtle-2n5c)